# Access files on a shared partition from within an application in a dual boot setup

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, permissions, installed-programs

I recently switched to Linux Ubuntu 20.04 in a dual boot scenario for the sake of video gaming in a restricted hardware setting.

I have Windows on my large 1TB SSD, and Ubuntu on another SSD, and they both share a partition for media such as music, videos, photos and of course documents.

Therefore I created Links in the `/home` directory that redirect to the shared folders on the shared partition. Using the GNOME Files app, this seems to work rather flawlessly, but it's the other applications that keep stirring things up.

i.e., when I want to use the Signal Desktop app to share some files, I click on the "add"-button and end up with the view of the folder structures below.

[image: screenshot signal upload window]

The links appear to be broken in the left column, and the Bookmarks in the left column that also should direct to the shared partition within the "Documents"-Folder do not work. In particular, the Links are interpreted as files rather than folders. It seems that the application doesn't understand that there is another partition it should be able to access.

Another example with similar effects would be the foobar2000 music player that I cant get to add the music files on the shared partition. It doesn't even show up in the app's [file manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lSGS2.png), and neither do the links in the /home directory.

[image: file manager]

Overall, this is an annoying situation. How can I make these third-party programs understand that there is a partition full of fancy stuff for them to access?

Only Silverlight here is the necessitated use of the fantastic Bandcamp website in order to get some music pumping.

Comment: I think both apps mentioned are snaps and what you're seeing is the consequence of the characteristic snap confinement. Try searching for both in Ubuntu Software, open each respective page and you should see a big red "Permissions" button. Use it to enable mass storage support and that should give you access to anything under /media or /mnt as well which should cover your needs. A separated data partition and links is a sound and smart strategy (and makes you a commendable above average user) but it doesn't work for snaps.

Comment: Well, thanks for flattering me :)
snaps seem like a whole new rabbit hole to go down to. I did what you suggested and checked the box "Read/Write files on removable storage devices", which comes closest to what you described, and I think that Ubuntu views all partitions as external which can be auto-mounted by suited protocols. However, the problem persists, at least with the shared partition, which, following some tutorial, I mounted at /data instead of /media.  Should I just remount the partition?
Does the snap confinement also happen when I use the `sudo apt-get install`-command?

Comment: Only userspace and /media and /mnt for snaps I'm afraid. And traditional debs aren't confined but there's at least one exception where the deb actually installs a snap: Chromium.